# Printing superscript characters not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I run the following print statement `System.out.print("⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹");`
The output is `?¹²³??????`
Does anyone know why only some superscript characters are valid?

Comment: What type of output are you getting in Eclipse?

Comment: For me all the characters are printed properly in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Eclipse Console 'Preferences' (right click) and select the 'Fixed width console' check box.